# wso2 IS 5 with SP1 - No Established Sessions corresponding to Session Indexes provided

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I have configured my application as service provider and configured as saml sso for authentication. Login is working fine but failing logout functionality (SLO).

**Error:**

> No Established Sessions corresponding to Session Indexes provided.

**Here is my configuration:**

```
<SessionDataPersist>
    <Enable>true</Enable>
    <RememberMePeriod>20060</RememberMePeriod>
    <CleanUp>
            <Enable>true</Enable>
            <Period>480</Period>
            <TimeOut>20160</TimeOut>
    </CleanUp>
    <Temporary>false</Temporary>
</SessionDataPersist>

The samlp:LogoutRequest contains
**< samlp:SessionIndex>ba164b2e-fed5-4c0c-98c2-01542d854df < /samlp:SessionIndex>**
```

problem:

the above mentioned sessionIndex is present in idn_auth_session_store table as SAMLSSOParticipantCache. But I am getting the above mentioned exception.

Could someone help me out resolving the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Request message <samlp:LogoutRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Destination="http://sw.ind.domain.steelwedge.com
:9763/samlsso" ID="eednggmdldkfbgmoad" IssueInstant="2016-01-21T11:11:23.317Z" Reason="Single Logout" Version="2.0"><saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">plocal</saml:Iss
uer><saml:NameID xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">COMPASSAG
/steelwedge</saml:NameID><samlp:SessionIndex>ba164b2e-fed5-4c0c-98c2-201542d854df</samlp:SessionIndex></samlp:LogoutRequest>

Comment: [2016-01-21 03:13:28,498] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.LogoutRequestProcessor} 
[2016-01-21 03:13:28,514] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet} -  Invalid SAML SSO Logout Request
[2016-01-21 03:13:28,514] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet} -  Error when processing the authent
ication request!
org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityException: Invalid SAML SSO Logout Request

Comment: Try again after clearing the cache and cookies in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried many times but issue still exists. Seems problem is not with browser session. Problem is with session handling in IS.

Comment: Probably you are sending two logout request. First request may successful and clear the cache and databases. If you send a request again, `No Established Sessions corresponding to Session Indexes provided` error may come. Plz update the question with full log